# On a Probability notation - $\mathbb{E}[X(.)|\mathcal{F}]_G$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

What could mean this notation :

$\mathbb{E}[X(.)|\mathcal{F}]_G$ ?

where G : $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,P, \mathcal{F})$. X could be a process like that : $X:\Omega \times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
My question is on the sub $G$.

Comment: Maybe this is $u(G)$ where $E(X(t)\mid\mathcal F)=u(t)$ almost surely, for every $t$?

Comment: what do you mean by $u$ ?

Comment: There is also this notation $\mathbb{E}[X(v)|\mathcal{F}]_{v=G}$ maybe it could help tu understand ...

Comment: This (which should have been included in the question) fully confirms the suggestion in my first comment. Re $u$, as is written in said comment, $E(X(t)\mid \mathcal F)$ is a random variable depending on $t$, and we denote it $u(t)$.

Comment: Do you have a reference (a course/book/article) that use this notation ?

Comment: No. And I would not recommend it, unless it is explained in detail.

Comment: Range of $G$ = $\Omega$ of $X$ ?

Comment: Then why we have this equality ? $$\mathbb{E}[\ \mathbb{\hat{E}}(X(.)|\mathcal{F}_t)_G K(G) |\mathcal{F}_t] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{\hat{E}}(X(.)|\hat{\mathcal{F}}_t)_u K(G) dP^G(u)$$ Where $\hat{\mathcal{F}}_t=\cap_{s>t}\mathcal{F}_s\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $K(.)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable and $\hat{E}$ the expectation w.r.t $\mathbb{P}\otimes\eta$ (with $\eta$ probability measure on ($\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$).

*My question is notably on the expectation with $\hat{\mathcal{F}}$.*